# Kotlin Coroutine Channel not queueing

Tags: multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope, kotlin-coroutine-channel

**Use case:**
The function `processData()` can be called by many coroutines in parallel, but they need to be processed one after the other like a queue and should not run in parallel.

I used channels to achieve this but still the function is executed in parallel.
How can I ensure that `processData()` is run only after an ongoing execution of the same function has completed ? What am I doing wrong here ?

My Implementation :

```
class MyClass {

    private var channel: Channel<Long> = Channel()

    //this is public function other classes can invoke in parallel, which inturn invokes processData.
    suspend fun call() {
        coroutineScope {
            launch {
                val timeStamp = System.currentTimeMillis()
                Log.i("testing", "send :$timeStamp")
                channel.send(timeStamp)
            }
            processData(channel.receive())
        }
    }


    private suspend fun processData(timeStamp : Long) {
        Log.i("testing", "processData: start :$timeStamp")
        delay(5000L)
        Log.i("testing", "processData: end :$timeStamp")
        return
    }
}
```

*Logcat logs have been cleaned up for readability including values of `System.currentTimeMillis()` has been replaced with 1,2,3,4 & 5.*

**Expected Logcat :(Not accurate but just general idea)**

```
send :1
processData: start :1
send :2
send :3
send :4
send :5
processData: end :1
processData: start :2
processData: end :2
processData: start :3
processData: end :3
processData: start :4
processData: end :4
processData: start :5
processData: end :5
```

**Current Logcat :**

```
send :1
processData: start :1

send :2
processData: start :2

send :3
processData: start :3

send :4
processData: start :4

send :5
processData: start :5

processData: end :1
processData: end :2
processData: end :3
processData: end :4
processData: end :5
```

Comment: Do you need `call()` to wait for `processData()` to finish or return immediately?

Comment: I don't need `call()` to wait for `processData()` to finish. `processData()` doesn't return any value and can take a while to complete. I want to make sure `processData()` is not executed in parallel by multiple callers.

Comment: If I'm seeing this correctly your `call` does wait for `processData` because its called within its coroutineScope. Also use of channel here makes no sense, `call` launches a coroutine to push something to the channel and proceeds to consume whatever is (or will be) in the channel (for example - data pushed by previous `call`). You probably want to have a completely separate processing job launched within (viewmodel?) that will keep running and handling messages sent to the channel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using Mutex:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.sync.Mutex

class MyClass {
     val mutex = Mutex()
     ...
     private suspend fun processData(index: Int) {
         mutex.withLock {
             //do your non parallel stuff
         }
     }
}
```

Nice tutorial:
https://medium.com/mobile-app-development-publication/mutex-for-coroutines-5f4a4ca60763

Comment: This had me going crazy for a sometime now, great solution, thank you friend